# Unbound symbols in reactor data after loading the drawing

Tags: autolisp

I have added a modification reactor to my table. The reactor has a callout function in it's data. `callout` is a function `am:trench-updated`

```
(vlr-pers 
  (vlr-object-reactor 
     (list table)
     (list (cons :am:dictionary dictionary)
           (cons :am:modified callout))
     (list (cons :vlr-modified 'am:table-modified))))
```

In the reactor I extract these callouts from the list:

```
(defun am:object-get (object field)
    (cdr (assoc field object)))

(defun am:table-modified (reactor-object)
  (setq reactor-data (vlr-data reactor-object)
        callout (am:object-get reactor-data :am:modified))
  (apply callout (list ...)))
```

It works fine until I save-load the drawing. After the load, `callout` contains the correct name, but nil value.

[image: Before and after]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An AutoLISP function will only be defined within the scope of the document namespace and will therefore need to be redefined when the document (drawing file) is reopened. I'm unsure why such function would be undefined following a save operation however.

I would personally suggest that you avoid the use of persistent reactors in favour of rebuilding transient reactors on drawing startup. In my experience, persistent reactors are never truly persistent.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to rebuild reactors on drawing setup? I'm guessing you would need to save your data in the drawing's dictionary and iterate over them on the document load. But I can't imagine how to run a function on drawing startup, since your lisp file may not be loaded at that time.

Comment: The AutoLISP file would be configured to load on drawing startup by the user (using a `load` expression in the `acaddoc.lsp` file, for example); the data used by the VL Reactors would indeed need to be stored either in a drawing dictionary, extended entity data (xdata), or ldata.

Comment: but the function must be save as a string by it's name. How to call a function with parameters by it's name?

Comment: Why must the function name be saved as a string? Perhaps you can gain some pointers from the code for my [Associative Textbox](http://lee-mac.com/assoctextbox.html) application - this program stores the association data as xdata attached to the objects and rebuilds transient reactors when the program is loaded.

Comment: It's just a property of my table that I would like to keep - it's reactor does not directly call the method that updates the corresponding objects. Instead, it stores a function in it's data. This function must be called when that particular table is modified. That way you could have different tables that react differently but share a reactor. Anyway, the answer is enough to make what I need, just not the exact way I want. Thanks.